# Needing to see if an XML element exists through an XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I am working with an XML and am attempting to transform it for another software program.  The XML was acquired through a web-service, and unfortunately it's not well-formed (as you can see it doesn't even provide the XML version).  Here's the XML produced by the program's web-service:

```
<Metadata>
      <Entry Group="SYSTEM">
        <Tag>MOB ID</Tag>
        <Value>060a2b340101010101010f0013-000000-55b9344b27dd00a6-    060e2b347f7f-2a80</Value>
      </Entry>
      <Entry Group="SYSTEM">
        <Tag>Moniker</Tag>
        <Value>1|F9E3A1A4-4CB9-45CC-A590-77A5D733B633|*|3055376|*</Value>
      </Entry>
      <Entry Group="SYSTEM">
        <Tag>CFPS</Tag>
        <Value>29.97</Value>
      </Entry>
      <Entry Group="SYSTEM">
        <Tag>Created By</Tag>
        <Value>rjensen</Value>
      </Entry>
      <Entry Group="SYSTEM">
        <Tag>Creation Date</Tag>
        <Value>2015-07-29T16:15:07.000-0400</Value>
      </Entry>
      <Entry Group="USER">
        <Tag>Display Name</Tag>
        <Value>LTW_NatLocal_1529_H.Sub.01.transfer</Value>
      </Entry>
      <Entry Group="SYSTEM">
        <Tag>Duration</Tag>
        <Value>00;04;13;29</Value>
      </Entry>
      <Entry Group="SYSTEM">
        <Tag>End</Tag>
        <Value>00;07;16;18</Value>
      </Entry>
      <Entry Group="SYSTEM">
        <Tag>Media Status</Tag>
        <Value>partial</Value>
      </Entry>
      <Entry Group="SYSTEM">
        <Tag>Modified By</Tag>
        <Value>rjensen</Value>
      </Entry>
      <Entry Group="SYSTEM">
        <Tag>Modified Date</Tag>
        <Value>2015-07-29T16:15:11.000-0400</Value>
      </Entry>
      <Entry Group="SYSTEM">
        <Tag>Path</Tag>
        <Value>/Sent to Playback/Week31/Wednesday/060a2b340101010101010f0013-000000-55b9344b27dd00a6-060e2b347f7f-2a80</Value>
      </Entry>
      <Entry Group="SYSTEM">
        <Tag>Start</Tag>
        <Value>00;03;02;19</Value>
      </Entry>
      <Entry Group="SYSTEM">
        <Tag>Tracks</Tag>
        <Value>V1-9 A1-2 TC1</Value>
      </Entry>
      <Entry Group="SYSTEM">
        <Tag>Type</Tag>
        <Value>sequence</Value>
      </Entry>
      <Entry Group="USER">
        <Tag>Video ID</Tag>
        <Value>test55</Value>
      </Entry>
      <Locator>
        <Label>NK IN</Label>
        <Color>Blue</Color>
        <Timecode>00;03;24;17</Timecode>
        <Username>jolive</Username>
        <Track>V7</Track>
      </Locator>
      <Locator>
        <Label>BUG/Phone Number/Watermark OUT</Label>
        <Color>Magenta</Color>
        <Timecode>00;04;01;02</Timecode>
        <Username>jolive</Username>
        <Track>V8</Track>
      </Locator>
      <Locator>
        <Label>NK OUT</Label>
        <Color>Blue</Color>
        <Timecode>00;03;41;06</Timecode>
        <Username>jolive</Username>
        <Track>V7</Track>
      </Locator>
      <Locator>
        <Label>BUG/Phone Number/Watermark IN</Label>
        <Color>Magenta</Color>
        <Timecode>00;04;46;13</Timecode>
        <Username>jolive</Username>
        <Track>V8</Track>
      </Locator>
      <Locator>
        <Label>BUG/Phone Number/Watermark OUT</Label>
        <Color>Magenta</Color>
        <Timecode>00;04;30;04</Timecode>
        <Username>jolive</Username>
        <Track>V8</Track>
      </Locator>
      <Locator>
        <Label>BUG/Phone Number/Watermark IN</Label>
        <Color>Magenta</Color>
        <Timecode>00;03;41;21</Timecode>
        <Username>jolive</Username>
        <Track>V8</Track>
      </Locator>
    </Metadata>
```

Essentially, it's a bunch of different elemenets.  However, the challenge comes when if no data is supplied (by the original database that produced the xml), there will be no element.  For example, if there was no entry in the Video ID there would be no Video ID element.

My questions is:  Is there a way I could 1) See if the element exists using the xsl and 2) grab the corresponding value?

I've tried this and I can't seem to get it to work:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:x="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult"  version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>  

    <xsl:template match="/">


        <soa:Label identifier="cd8fb02d-d7a7-49c0-b461-d2d6149cb822" name="Style_Sheet_Test" description="" instance="7ed356b0-8559-42a8-9051-91652d771336" signature="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" xmlns:soa="urn:telestream.net:soa:core">
           <xsl:if test="Created By">
                <xsl:value-of select="Created By">
                </xsl:value-of>
           </xsl:if>
        </soa:Label>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. If there are two possible types of input, show us two examples of input and the expected result of each. -- BTW, the input you show us now **is** well-formed XML.

Comment: You're wrong to suggest this is not well-formed XML. The absence of an XML declaration is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to find `<Tag>` nodes where the value is created by.

Your `test` and `select` statements are not valid XPaths.  The input there should be something like this:

```
<xsl:if test="//Entry[Tag='Created By']">
```

Which is basically saying "if there's any Tag node at any level whose text reads 'Created By', return true".  You then need to decide which elements/attributes you want to select - `Created By` isn't an attribute or element though, it's a text **value** of an element.

I'll go one step further and suggest that what you most likely want is a template to match nodes where the `Tag`'s text reads "Created By", which might look like this:

```
<xsl:template match="Metadata/Entry[Tag='Created By']">
    <xsl:value-of select="@Group" />
</xsl:template>
```

Assuming that the context was `/`.

Comment: Agreed, except I would write it `<xsl:template match="Metadata/Entry[Tag='Created By']"><xsl:value-of select="@Group" /></xsl:template>`

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why I always end up doing that.  thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: This is very close to what I'm trying to do, which is ultimate sort through all the Tag values.  However, instead of getting the attribute, I need to get the Tag's sibling.  So in this particular example, I need that filtering you wrote above, but get the value of the Value element.  So I need to find <Tag> Created by</Tag>, then get the value of <Value>, which in this case is rjensen.  Hope that makes sense!